# using a string variable as object name in twig

Tags: twig, craftcms

Is there a way in Twig to use a variable as an object name?

Sth like this: If foo is defined then use the value of foo as the name of the object, if not then use some arbitrary string?

This example is not working but I hope it shows the idea:

```
{% for block in [foo is defined ? foo : 'someThing'].someProperty %}
```

So the result if foo is not defined would be

```
someThing.someProperty
```

and if foo is the string "someThingElse" it would be

```
someThingElse.someProperty
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every variable is stored in the special variable `_context`, chain this with the filter `default` to take care of `foo` possibly being undefined,

```html
{% for block in _context[foo|default('someThingElse')].someProperty %}
    {{ block }}
{% endfor %}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/tkit24)